# How to split a table by the value in a given column?

Tags: matlab

I have a table, say,

```
1,  2,   3,  4,  'good'
4, 32,  22,  1,  'bad'
2,  3,   1,  4,  'good'
9,  1,  23,  4,  'bad'
```

I want to split this table by two classes `'good'` and `'bad'`.

Which means, after splitting the table, I will have,

table one:

```
1,  2,   3,  4,  'good'
2,  3,   1,  4,  'good'
```

table two:

```
4, 32,  22,  1,  'bad'
9,  1,  23,  4,  'bad'
```

Is there any easy way to do this without reinventing the wheel?

I am using MATLAB 2018a.

Comment: have you checked [findgroup](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) documentation, there are examples to split tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your table is this:

```
>> tbl = 
A   B    C   D   Rating
-----------------------
1,  2,   3,  4,  'good'
4, 32,  22,  1,  'bad'
2,  3,   1,  4,  'good'
9,  1,  23,  4,  'bad'
```

You can do the following:

```
table1 = tbl( strcmp( tbl.Rating, 'good' ), : );
table2 = tbl( strcmp( tbl.Rating, 'bad' ), : );
```

This creates logical indexing arrays depending on the string in the `Rating` column, and assigns those rows to the new tables.